# Connecting to postgresql database remotely

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

how to Connect postgresql using bookshelf.js from a remote system instead of using "host: localhost"

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add code to see what you tried and so we can help you debug the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the hostname or IP address of the host, instead of 'localhost', like:

```
host: "dbserver.example.com"
```

or

```
host: "203.0.113.1"
```

Note: if the database is not using the default port (5432) you should also specify it. For example for port 5050:

```
host: "dbserver.example.com:5050"
```

or

```
host: "203.0.113.1:5050"
```